# Cannot map Enum JSON, unable to find 'aUSD' in token in api.tx.currencies.transfer

Tags: polkadot-js, transactions, transfer, polkadot-js-extension, acala

I'm trying to transfer aUSD test token from one wallet to another on my dapp using Polkadot.js wallet. Sender's wallet is connected to Mandala TC7 test.

I read [this](https://wiki.acala.network/integrate/integration/token-transfer#currencies.transfer) at Acala's site and I'm trying to use it as below.

```
const transfer = polkadot.tx.currencies.transfer('5F1pZeuR...GmZRSZuK', 'aUSD',100000000000);
```

But I'm getting the error below. My sender's wallet has 30 aUSD.

`bundle-polkadot-types.js:8021 Uncaught (in promise) Error: createType(Call):: Call: failed decoding currencies.transfer:: Struct: failed on args: {"dest":"MultiAddress","currency_id":"{\"_enum\":{\"Token\":\"AcalaPrimitivesCurrencyTokenSymbol\",\"DexShare\":\"(AcalaPrimitivesCurrencyDexShare,AcalaPrimitivesCurrencyDexShare)\",\"Erc20\":\"H160\",\"StableAssetPoolToken\":\"u32\",\"LiquidCrowdloan\":\"u32\",\"ForeignAsset\":\"u16\"}}","amount":"Lookup48"}:: Struct: failed on currency_id: {"_enum":{"Token":"AcalaPrimitivesCurrencyTokenSymbol","DexShare":"(AcalaPrimitivesCurrencyDexShare,AcalaPrimitivesCurrencyDexShare)","Erc20":"H160","StableAssetPoolToken":"u32","LiquidCrowdloan":"u32","ForeignAsset":"u16"}}:: Cannot map Enum JSON, unable to find 'aUSD' in token, dexshare, erc20, stableassetpooltoken, liquidcrowdloan, foreignasset at createTypeUnsafe (bundle-polkadot-types.js:8021:20)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the extrinsics page, the currencyId is an Enum indicating the type of transfer.

So you need to pass the `Token` explicitly. This should do the trick -

```js
const transfer = polkadot.tx.currencies.transfer(
  // dest
  '5F1pZeuR...GmZRSZuK', 
  // currencyId, enum
  { Token: 'AUSD' },
  // amount
  100000000000
);
```